# PHP - How to check if string have 0 and 1 or 0 or 1

Tags: php, string, return

I have this function:

```
function return_a_number($source) {
  switch ($source) {
    case "0&0&0&0":
      return 0;
    case "0&0&1&1":
      return 1;
    case "1&1&1&1":
      return 2;
  }
}
```

Where $source have an ipotetic number concatenated with &.

How can i return 0 if $source have only '0' characters or 1 if have '0' and '1' characters or 2 if have only '1' characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
// If there is a 0, ( check if there's also a one -> 1 or 0 ) : else only 1s => 2
return strpos($source, '0') !== false ? ( strpos($source, '1') !== false ? 1 : 0 ) : 2;
```

You could of course also write a regex, but why make it complicated if it works that simple. You might want to catch an empty string depending on your input.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that something like `$source = "1"` would produce a result of `2`, which is obviously wrong. Equally, a input of `0&1` would produce a result of `1`, which is also wrong.

Comment: `$source = "1" would produce a result of 2`- He asked: `or 2 if have only '1' characters`
And also: `or 1 if have '0' and '1' ` - as you said: `0&1 would produce a result of 1` - Seems right to me.

Comment: I see, perhaps I missread the question then. I was under the impression 0 was for 0 only, 1 was for 1 only, and 2 was for both.

Comment: Yes, thats true!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the logic in your function should be, easy to understand and covers all three cases. Keep in mind that you must always check for 0 and 1 together first, then do it individually

```
if (strpos($source, '0') !== false && strpos($source, '1') !== false) {
    return 0;
 }
elseif (strpos($source, '0') !== false) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 2
}
```

You can put one more 'elseif' instead of the last 'else' if you might get different result than the 3 outcomes you mentioned